# What is the equivalent of easeOutExpo in Flex easing effects?

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4, flex-spark

In Tweener there is a transition of type "easeOutExpo". What is the equivalent in Flex easing classes - listed here [1]?

**More Context**:

Here is the Tweener code:

```
Tweener.addTween(container, {width:w, height:h, time:0.25, transition:"easeOutExpo"});
```

Here is the instance that I want to have the easeOutExpo transition type:

```
        <s:Scale 
                 scaleYFrom=".5" 
                  scaleYTo="1"
                  scaleXFrom=".5"
                  scaleXTo="1"
                  duration="250"
                  autoCenterTransform="true"
                  applyChangesPostLayout="true"
                  />
```

[1] http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS91E85D63-A025-4c46-B758-A275D4D3B3FC.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be the [`Power`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/effects/easing/Power.html) easing, with [`easeInFraction`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/effects/easing/EaseInOutBase.html#easeInFraction) set to `0`. You'll need to figure out the proper exponent by some trial and error if you want to match the algorithm used by Tweener.

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:Power
        id='expoEaseOutEquivalent'
        easeInFraction='0'
        exponent='8' />

    <s:Scale
        easer='{expoEaseOutEquivalent}'
        scaleYFrom='.5' 
        scaleYTo='1'
        scaleXFrom='.5'
        scaleXTo='1'
        duration='250'
        autoCenterTransform='true'
        applyChangesPostLayout='true' />
</fx:Declarations>
```